# How to change TimeStamp godaddy server Time Zone in Php or PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I submit my form my timestamp function uses GoDaddy Server time. But I need to change my time zone to `"(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi"`. How can I change my time zone through PHP, PhpMyAdmin, or GoDaddy server. If there is any possible option please help.

Comment: You can use `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');` within your config file

Answer (score 0):

If you have shared server, then ask hosting server person to do that for you. will get help from hosting provider service center.[Create a ticket for it]

If you have dedicate server, then you can open the putty and connect to server for changing it.

Comment: But can I Know what type of server it is ? Shared or Dedicate ?